# how to run a shell command in the same shell process that vim was started

Tags: shell

I want to source a file in the same shell process vim was started, from within vim as an ex command. As far as I know, vim creates a new subshell and run commands. <s>In addition to that, If I source a file, and then start vim, vim does not detect the recently added environment variables.</s> (VIm Actually do detect recent exported variables)

Basically, I want to conditionally add some directories to vim's path variable. For the condition, I need to check existence of an environment variable that is come from a file that is sourced.

So, I source a file. It adds some env variable to the current shell. Open vim, run a vim function that checks the existence of an environment variable; if it exists, then append some directories to vim's `path` variable.

One solution that came to my mind is that when sourcing that file, set an alias: `vim='vim -c "set path+=/path/to/dirs/"'`. But I want to implement the idea in vim script, if that is possible.

Os: `linux`
vim: `v8.2`

Comment: Vim isn't a "subshell" or a shell process at all. The shell from which you run Vim spawns a child process...a Vim process. Then when you do something like `:!ls` Vim spawns its own child process in which a shell program runs. So what you're requesting isn't really applicable.

Comment: @BLayer thanks for shedding light on the question. Feel free to edit the question.

Comment: @Quasímodo The problem is when I source a file and then start vim, vim does not detect the recently added environment variables. `echo expand('$MYVAR')'` does not print the value of the variable.

Comment: @Ali Yep. A child only inherits environment variables when it's spawned. All you can do is define the environment variable in Vim itself...`:let $FOO = "value"`

Comment: @BLayer Is there a command that runs a command in another shell process (given a process ID and a command string)? I couldn't find something from googling.

Comment: Not unilaterally. The target has to be involved...i.e. you'd have to set up some form of interprocess communication (e.g. shared pipe). Or if you're running tmux you could send commands to another shell's terminal.

Comment: Ugh, I meant "named pipe"...I was thinking of "shared memory" at the same time. :P

Comment: @BLayer :) thanks for the hint. I will look into that.

Comment: Sure. The key command is `mkfifo`. Super easy to use. Don't know if they'll fit the bill but it doesn't hurt to look.

Comment: That being said, if it's straightforward you might be better off just parsing the file you want to source (perhaps just grepping it) and setting up the environment directly in Vim (per my earlier comment). Okay, gotta go. Will check back later.

Comment: @BLayer I want to automate thing and this way, I guess, it kinda defeats the purpose.

Comment: @BLayer I'm stupid. I mistyped the name of the env variable. Vim actually detects the exported env variables. I'll edit the question and add some explanation there. I am sorry.

Comment: Some information after the horizontal rule would be better in an answer than as part of the question. For that reason, please [edit] it out and place it in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you run under *nix (including MSYS2/Cygwin) then you can suspend Vim process with <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> (see `:h suspend`). This will bring you back to the Vim's parent process (i.e. parent shell). Use `fg` to get back as usual. Won't work under plain Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I reached to what I needed but the answer to this question
As @BLayer explained in comments, It can't be done uninternally.

> you'd have to set up some form of interprocess communication (e.g. named pipe).

You can also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52996994/13041067) post and the explanation after it for further information related to this question.